# What does [parametertype[]]$Parameter mean?

Tags: powershell

I have seen PowerShell function parameters defined using the syntax `param([parametertype[]]$Parameter)` as well as `param([parametertype]$Parameter)`.

Personally, I have always used the latter with (as far as I can tell) no problems. Can anyone explain what (if any) is the difference and why both are allowed and work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[parametertype[]]$Parameter` is a `parametertype` **array** of `$Parameter`

`[parametertype]$Parameter` is a `$Parameter` of `parametertype`

i.e.

```
> [string]$param_s = "parameter"
> [string[]]$param_a = "parameter", "param2", "param3"
> $param_s[1]
a
> $param_a[1]
param2
```

Note how `param_s` is a plain string and accesses the second position in the string when accessing index `[1]` compared to what's returned by `param_a[1]`

When used by the `param` keyword in a function / cmdlet definition, it just ensures the function will be passed correct data type

Answer (score 0):

in powershell you don't have to define what parameter you are using but you can.
sometimes it can be handy if you want to define a parameter as [mandatory] for example.
in your example you defind an array type `param[]` and single type.
you can read more about [Defining Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx).